# Understanding the Inclusion of "of" and its Impact on Sentence Nuance

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, I'm curious about why the "of" is not omitted in "of the ABO blood groups." Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how the nuance of the sentence would change if "of" were to be omitted. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what it means in grammatical terms.

> A major shift in the approach to physical anthropology occurred at the beginning of the 20th century with the discovery of genetic principles and of the ABO blood groups.

Comment: No reason. No difference.